# jQuery's val() method change doesn't seem to change the DOM

Tags: jquery, forms, attributes

Doing `$("#someId").val("newValue")` doesn't change the DOM --
I can retrieve this value with `$("#someId").val()`, but the element in the DOM still doesn't have a value attribute.

How do I set the value of an input component and also change the DOM?

I'm using `jQuery 1.5.1`.

Comment: if you are using the firebug, there is a bug in it about updating the dom, you must click the window object to refresh it :)

Comment: type in an answer Val so I can up it :)

Comment: @Val, where I should click on window object? In DOM tab?

Comment: check my answer and it should make a bit more sense.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

.val() **does** change the DOM. For example this:

```
$("#someId").val("newValue");

alert(document.getElementById('someId').value);
```

alerts 'newValue'.

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ykVxj/).

If you want to change the *default* value to be used in form resets, try this:

```
$("#someId").attr("defaultValue", "newValue");
```

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7vwcr/).

Comment: @Alex: Please post a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) example that demonstrates what you say. Maybe you are not looking at an up to date DOM - see the comment by Val.

Comment: @rsp, same in Web Inspector... You wrote appropriate example, but issue still exist... Inspecting element in any browser, says, that there aren't "value" attribute...

Comment: @Alex: I just checked and both Safari and Firefox show the correct value. Besides if it wasn't in the DOM then document.getElementById('someId').value wouldn't return that value. Are you sure you're looking in the right place?

Comment: @rsp: yes, that why I'm confused... OK, there's a screenshot http://img851.imageshack.us/img851/8295/screenshot20110308at338.png, look at inspected element, and find out that there's no "value" attribute. Chrome, Mac OS X

Comment: @Alex: You're looking at the source HTML, not the DOM. When you right-click the element in Firefox and select "Inspect element" click on the DOM tab in the bottom-right window and look for the "value" property. Is it there?

Comment: @rsp, yes value atribute there... Now I got it. But issue still exist when I generate appropriate DOM in memory. For instance, I have to load some DOM, and set for all input's some value, via .val(). Value will set, but in source there are no value attribute. And later when I reset a form, via .reset(), it makes all input field blank, but shouldn't, as reset works only for edited fields... Hope I explained why I need exactly changing real HTML. In the other hand, I can add and change any attribute via .attr(), but this doesn't work for "value"...

Comment: @alex as I explained on my answer, fire-bug only manipulates the html source codes so it can make you life easier to debug, and track changes on dynamic pages. with that in mind you will always have bugs that don't always work, or haven't been implemented yet

Comment: @Val, it's not about firebug. It's about how to set attribute value in jquery in memory, in this case it have to looks like:
<input type="text" value="bla-bla"/>
But it only set value to DOM, and not represent in HTML. For this reason, form reset doesn't work as should be

Comment: you driving me mad lol :) the HTML tab on firebug does not update `value` attr but it does in DOM,

Comment: @Val, yes exactly! And that's why form reset doesn't work as should be. OK I have to write an example with a form...

Comment: @Alex: What you probably want to change is not *value* but *defaultValue*. See example in the update to my answer.

Comment: See this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/ykVxj/48/ The outerHTML property does not show a change in `value`. Can I conclude that DOM isn't updated but just the property `value` gets updated.

Answer (score 3):

This

```
$("#someId").val("newValue")
```

will change the value of the input element.

This

```
$("#someId").attr("value","newValue")
```

will change the value of the value attribute.

The second may help if you want to write the element. So, for example:

```
$("#someId").val("newValue")
$("#someId").attr("value","newValue")
write($("#someId").parent())
```

-will result in the new value being rendered, whereas

```
$("#someId").val("newValue")
write($("#someId").parent())
```

-will just show the original value.

Answer (score 2):

**Answer**
if you are using the firebug, there is a bug in it about updating the dom, you must click the 
window object to refresh it :)

**Explanation** 
@alex i was reading comments below. on @rsp answer and you seem to confuse the dom with the html tree a dom, is a tree like list of values used to keep track of values. and yes click dom tab, or right click the element in question and then inspect it in dom, values, changes dont show up on firebug, because of security reasons that prevent anything other than a browser to change its values `or` possibly because fire bug, has got it wrong and they probably working on it :)

Answer (score 1):

Reading from "rsp" answer and discussion:

you want to change the HTML source, not the DOM.

Therefore use:

```
$('#YOUR_ID option[value="YOUR_VALUE"]').attr('selected', 'selected');
```

The method .val() does not change the HTML source.

Cheers.
Stefano