# Jquery (input/textarea).val(): how is it adding content without changing the DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

take a look at the JsFiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/ru2Fg/2/

Essentially, it starts with two `textarea`s: one empty, one with stuff inside, and an `input type=text`. I was under the impression that to put stuff in an `input` you change it's `value`, and to put stuff in a `textarea` you add the text as a child to the node.

I perform a `$(...).val(...)` to change their contents. And their contents *do* change.

However, the DOM looks exactly the same! I'm printing out the 3 elements with `console.log()`; they seem unchanged. I look at them with chrome's inspect element: they seem unchanged.

I've looked at [jQuery's val() method change doesn't seem to change the DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5232591/jquery-val-change-dom), but that question concludes it's something funny with firebug not refreshing the HTML it displays. In this case, i'm quite sure inspect element displays the *current* html that exists on the page: i've seen the `left` attribute changing furiously when things are scrolling, for example. I'm also checking it using the console, which tells me the same thing: nothing changed.

My eyes, though, tell me something *has* changed, as I'm seeing "10, omg, moo" instead of "blank, hello world, 2000". What's going on?

EDIT: I posted the wrong jsFiddle. This should be the correct one now

Comment: Firebug doesn't always display (in its HTML tab) the most current version of the DOM.  To "refresh" the displayed HTML in firebug, you can select a parent node (body is always a good choice), click "Edit", change anything (I usually add a space), and then click "Edit" again.  This seems to force Firebug to refresh it's displayed version of the DOM.

Comment: This isn't using Firebug though. And I'm doing a `console.log`, which should print out what the node is currently **is**, shouldn't it?

Comment: Ah, my mistake.  Kolink seems to have your real question well covered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a difference between the `value` *attribute* and the `value` *property*. When you type in the input box, you are changing the *property*, not the *attribute*. The attribute stays the same as when the document was loaded. Among other things, this means you can reset an input box to its default value with `elem.value = elem.getAttribute('value');`.

Similarly, if you have a drop-down `<select>` with one of the options having the `selected` attribute set, even if you choose a different option that attribute will still be there even though the `selected` property is now `false`.

The same applies to checkboxes and the `checked` attribute. The same also applies for the `disabled` attribute, and several other things too.

Comment: I had assumed that these attributes of the DOM were the "single source of truth" as to how the elements would be displayed, and that if you wanted to change their behaviour you changed the attributes.

It seems that what you are telling me is that these attributes are simply initializers for javascript variables, which then hold the state of the component. Is that correct?

Comment: That's more or less it, yes. There are some properties that are directly mapped to attributes (`style` in particular), but for the most part you should use the property rather than the attribute.

Answer (score 0):

It is in-fact changing the DOM, other ways the 10 woulnd't have showed up in the text area anyway. The problem is in the firebug itself(at list the old one), I am not sure if it is still available in the new ones.

To verify, you can use the web console of firefox or console of chrome.

Comment: I am using Chrome's Inspect Element. And `console.log($("#cow"))`. Both are showing the DOM as unchanged. Are they both wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The DOM is completely loaded before anything jQuery happens, so technically the data inserted in the DOM isn't seen by debuggers. The debugging tools see only what is rendered so you won't be able to manipulate the "after the fact" data that arrives via jQuery. You could consider it "out of band" or fudging the DOM in a way. The same happens with AJAX. If you add in data or page content with AJAX methods like .load() you won't see it in the DOM.

An input box in jQuery has the val() method -- which is the value attribute, in the textarea, it is usually the html() method, what the textarea contains.

Comment: This isn't using Firebug though. I'm using Chrome Inspect Element, which I'm pretty sure shows the up-to-date DOM, as I said in the question. And I'm doing a `console.log`, which should print out what the node is currently **is**, shouldn't it? Both show it as unchanged.

Comment: console.log only prints out what the value is when you call console.log, so if your value assignment happens after that, it won't show up.

Comment: I know that. I am calling console.log after a do the `.val(...)` assignment. Can you look at the JsFiddle (now the correct one) and see if you can make sense of it? I've been using JS for about two years or so, and made a number of websites, so I think (I hope!) I've already covered most of the trivial possibilities =D

Comment: try this: http://jsfiddle.net/ru2Fg/4/ I think you have to set textareas with html() and then output the .val() of textboxes. You're only console.logging the object itself. Chrome sent back the correct values when I tried this.